# Hibernate identify connection leak?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using native query to update using Hibernate
I suspect it has a connection leak
Is there a code i can insert before and after the query to count the number of connections ?
so for example:

- before updateStatus 30 open connections
- after updateStatus 31 open connections

updateStatus method:

```
 public void updateStatus(){

        SessionFactory sessionfactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    try{
        Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        if(session.isConnected())
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query udpatestatusquery = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATUS='"+ status+ "' WHERE seq in ("+arrayOfIds+")");
            result = udpatestatusquery.executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }else{
            logger.error("Error! Failed to establish connection!);
        }
        Session s = session.get();
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
            session.remove();
        }
        sessionfactory.close();
    }catch (Exception exception) {
        Session s = session.get();
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
            session.remove();
        }
        sessionfactory.close();
        logger.error("Error! while updating! "+ exception.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is it getting reduced over the time? 2. How about in the same method getting connection count before and after by executing meta query?

Comment: Well, you don't have your `Session` in a `try-with-resources`. You don't close your `Session` in a `finally`. What do you expect to happen?